# Spell Check in Rich Text Box breaks in Run

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

I have a RichTextBox with SpellCheck activated. The problem is that I usually change the color of some letters applying a Foreground property, which adds a Run in the text, and the spell checker divides the words when it finds a Run. To be more clear, I live an example (it is in spanish because I have the SpellChecker configured in this language):

[image: Run problem example]

"estás" is correctly written, but the SpellChecker divides the word in "e", "s", "tá" and "s" because of the Runs. Does someone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not related to the multiple `Run` tags, that happening after applying some properties foreground/background/style to the parts of a word. The *SpellChecker* dialing with that kind of formatting without a problem.

This issue is happening when the default `RichTextBox` language does not set properly. For example, in case described in this post the following language setting `Language="es-ES"` should be defined:

```
RichTextBox x:Name="rtb" AllowDrop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            Language="es-ES" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <!-- Here should be content...  -->
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

When the default language does not set the `RichTextBox` uses `en-us` and if user type <kbd>s</kbd> it becomes from English - mixing alphabets is happening, that the *SpellChecker* detect as an error.

A similar problem related to mixing languages is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66093269/6630084).