# Edit RichTextBox Run element without splitting into multiple Run elements

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a WPF application with a `RichTextBox`. The text in the textbox is built up programmatically by spans and runs to a paragraph. Each sentence is a `Span`. Each word in a sentence is a `Run`. The user can edit the text.

The RichTextBox looks like this

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtRichSpeech">
    <FlowDocument x:Name="txtRichSpeechDoc">
        <Paragraph x:Name="txtRichSpeechContent"></Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

The text "This is just a test text." will have the structure

```
<Span>
    <Run>This</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>is</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>just</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>a</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>test</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>text.</Run>
</Span>
```

When the user edits for example the word "test" by adding an **E** in the middle I want `<Run>test</Run>` to become `<Run>teEst</Run>` but instead I get the following structure:

```
<Span>
    <Run>This</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>is</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>just</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>a</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>te</Run>
</Span>
<Run>E</Run>
<Span>
    <Run>st</Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run>text.</Run>
</Span>
```

How can I prevent this behavior and just have `<Run>teEst</Run>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is happening when the `Paste()` method used to paste the contents of the Clipboard in the `RichTextBox`. To prevent this behavior use the `InsertTextInRun()` method:

```
txtRichSpeech.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun(Clipboard.GetText());
```

A text will be inserted at the current caret position. Only if the caret is not scoped by a `Run` element, a `Run` will be inserted along with the text data.

**EDIT**

Another cause of this behavior is different language of the `RichTextBox` control and the current input language. Setting the `Language` property of the `RichTextBox` to the language of the current locale (input language) solves the problem. Example for Swedish:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtRichSpeech" Language="sv-SE">
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Thanx, but I’m not pasting. I’m just editing by setting caret position (mouse click) and typing a letter.

Comment: @Andreas: It's very strange. Because of when I type `E` after `te` in the `test` word it does not split the `<span>`! The `E` letter in English? May be you have additional event handles inside the `RichTextBox` that are affect formatting?

Comment: @Andreas: This can definitely happen if all text in English and than you typing `E`, but in another language.

Comment: @Andreas: Therefore, possible to groups inline elements without the `<Span>`. In most cases using the `<Paragraph>` will do the same markup.

Comment: The problem was the language! When setting the `Language` property of the `RichTextBox` it works as expected. I was far far away from that solution. Thanks a lot!